# Django values_list extremely slow on large dataset

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Getting a values_list in django is extremely slow on a large dataset (6M+ items).

I have a Django application with a DB structure like:

```py
class Taxon(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()

class Specimen(models.Model):
   taxon = models.ForeignKey("Taxon", related_name='specimens')

class Imaging(models.Model):
   taxon = models.ForeignKey("Specimen")
   image = models.ImageField(("Imaging"))
```

And need to get a list of all (images, taxon) belonging to a Taxon, if there are more than "100" images of that taxon.

This worked fine in development with a small database:

```py
image_list = list(Imaging.objects
.annotate(items_per_taxon=Count('specimen__taxon__specimens__images'))
                          .filter(items_per_taxon__gte=100)
                          .values_list('image', 'specimen__taxon'))
```

But takes 30 minutes on a full dataset (6M Taxon rows, and 2M image rows).

Is there a way of indexing the 'foreign key of a foreign key' or creating a virtual column in postgres that can make this faster?

Comment: Should `taxon = models.ForeignKey("Specimen")` on `Imaging` actually be `specimen = models.ForeignKey("Specimen")`?

Comment: No, the specimen is associated to a 'taxon' For example, your dog Rolf is a specimen. Rolf belongs to the taxon 'dog' and you can take several images of 'rolf' (the specimen). So 'rolf' has a property 'taxon' which would return 'dog'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your annotation could be more efficient if you group by specimen using `.values()` before the annotation to get a count of all the images for each specimen.

```
image_list = list(
    Imaging.objects
    .values('specimen')
    .annotate(items_per_taxon=Count('*'))
    .filter(items_per_taxon__gte=100)
    .values_list('image', 'specimen__taxon')
)
```

**Since you're new**, please be sure to mark an answer as correct using the check mark next to the answer and to vote if it helps you.